# Generating database tables' CREATE script

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, csv

I am working on an application which backs up database tables and stores their data as CSV. When I want to restore a table back to the database I use a 'model' table which creates an existing table based on the model. 
However there are multiple structures of these tables and I would like to generate the tables' 'Create' script and save it somewhere for restoring purposes. 
Is there anyway for this? I am only interested to do this via coding and not sql script because we are using both SQL Server and Oracle and this process will be automated for more than 3000 tables.

In the code below I create the table based on a table model:

```
 If ProductData.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) = 0 Then 'Does not exist
        'Create table based on a model
        Dim sqlCopyFromModel As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 0 * INTO " & sFileName & " FROM s_20130702;", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim i As Integer = sqlCopyFromModel.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        'Enter data from CSV file
        Dim sqlInsertDataFromCSV As New SqlCommand("BULK INSERT " & sFileName & " FROM '" & txtFilePath.Text.Trim & "' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW=2 )", con)

        con.Open()
        sqlInsertDataFromCSV.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("success")
```

Comment: Little alarming that you are creating a custom solution, surely there are in built tools in SQL (simply backing it up) that would be far more efficient?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish when a traditional database backup/restore is available?

Comment: @DMason It's a custom backup tool with special requirements.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Entity Framework (Code First)` model? It seems like that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use builtin package DBMS_METADATA where the function GET_DDL can give you the DDL ("create script") needed to create the table.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMP','SCOTT')
FROM DUAL;
```

(If you are trying to do something that is database independent and works both on SQL Server and Oracle, then you'd better not use "TOP 0" ;-)